# parameter specified as non-null is null: 'method kotlin.o0.d.t.e'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, kotlin, expo

I am trying to build an app where you can take images or import them from internal storage and perform some operations and display the image. I am using React Native for this. Everything works fine there are no errors while compiling, But when I import an image and do some operation and send it to display then an error prompts in my app stating "parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.o0.d.t.e, parameter setting"
I am using `ImagePicker` for editing.

[image]

Comment: Show me the code of the part where you get the error.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, The error occurred when using expo-camera with expo-image-picker. If you are using expo-image-picker above expo-camera, then you need to unmount the camera while picking.

That's how I solved it:

```
if (isFocused) {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ExpoCamera
      style={[
        styles.cameraPreview,
        { left: widthOffset, right: widthOffset },
      ]}
      ref={(ref) => {
        setCamera(ref);
      }}
      type={type}
    >
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={async () => {
            setIsFocused(false);
            const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
              mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
              allowsEditing: true,
              aspect: [1, 1],
              quality: 0.5,
            });
            if (!result.cancelled) {
              navigation.navigate("PhotoPreview", {
                photoTaken: result,
                callBackKey: "NewSupportReq",
              });
            } else {
              setIsFocused(true);
            }
          }}
        >
          <Icon
            name="photo-library"
            type="material-icons"
            color="white"
            size={30}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </ExpoCamera>
  </View>
);
} else {
return <></>;
}
```